# ReportViewer is not displaying data .

Tags: asp.net, report-viewer2010

I want to use Report Viewer in my project. 
i have 

1. CustomerDetails - Stored Procedure

2. CustomerDataset.xsd - in which i dragged n dropped the stored procedure. 

3. CustomerReport.rdlc - in which i have crated a table which and data set is 
CustomerDetails

4. CustomerReportViewer.aspx - in which the CustomerReoprt.rdlc is being binded.

now, i want to pass 2 values "chkeckInDate" and "checkOutDate" from 2 text box which are to be filled by use from "main.aspx" also i 'm calling my stored procedure from this file .

the report viewer is getting displayed but, the contents are not getting displayed (i have executed my stored procedure and it is running perfectly.)

How can i fix it? please help.

Comment: post the code that you are written in CustomerReportViewer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly understand where is the mistake, but I think you have the code under page_load event. Copy the code into button_click.

This is what I've used..

You must inport this:

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
```

You should pass the textbox value as parameter.

```
Dim yr As New ReportParameter("param1", TextBox1.Text)
    Try
        Me.your_TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet_name.table_name)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {yr})
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("try again")
    End Try
```

copy these two lines from page_load event into button_click.

```
Me.your_TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet_name.table_name)
Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Further, [watch this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxwd3h0gNNE)